# не могу привязать таблицы с разным кол-во атрибутов SSMS18 EXPRESS 19

Tags: sql, ssms

На первом скрине пишет, что кол-во столбцов отличается, на втором скрине убрал все столбцы в этом окне, но уже выводит другую тему. Тяжело описать это
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: надо сделать id первичным  ключом, и если требуется добавить составной уникальный индекс на какие-то столбцы. а не вот это вот с 5ю столбцами 3 из которых дублируют таблицу юзеров

Comment: @teran я хотел сделать автозаполнение таблицы заказов, чтобы человек не прописывал свое имя в заказе, оно само заполнило

Comment: реляционная БД подразумевает связи между таблицами. Человеку не надо прописывать повторно то, что у вас есть в другой таблице. Надо пользоваться функционалом предоставляемым СУБД и писать запросы соединяя таблицы. Возьмите и прочитайте какую-нибудь минимальную книгу по реляционным БД и нормализации данных сразу очень многие вопросы снимет.

Comment: @teran хорошо, спасибо